# How to find valid combinations in a table using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables.

One is Admin Table with all valid combinations and other is a Transaction table with the transactions.

I am trying to write a query which will give me the result of invalid combinations from transaction table.

The query should return the invalid transactions.

As you can see in the example below ABCD - TUV and IJKL - EFG are not valid combinations.

Admin Table

```
Column A    Column B
ABCD        XYZ
ABCD        EFG
EFGH        XYZ
IJKL        TUV
IJKL        XYZ
```

Comment: please improve example data

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name removed the example data. Any how I got the solution as below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can use NOT EXISTS e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS T WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                                 FROM ADMIN
                                               WHERE COMBINATION = T.COMBINATION)
```

Wether to use EXISTS or NOT IN depends largely on the data you're querying. 
you can find more info on the topic here
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074

Answer (score 0):

There is no example in your question, but you should use `NOT IN`.

For example :

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE combination NOT IN (SELECT combination FROM ADMIN)
```